# is it possible to add datasets using jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have tried datatables (datatables.net) and I like it it quite much, due to the simplicity and possibilities.

Now I'm at a point where I need to create new sets of data and I wonder if it is at all possible with datatables.
I'm afraid, datatables is just used for displaying data, not for editing existing sets of creating new sets.

Am I right?

Many thanks

**Update**:
I'm afraid I need to rephrase the question.
*Is it possible to use datatables as some kind of form to enter new data (and or edit existing data)?*
I can take care of adding (and or updating ) data on the server side myself.

Sorry for not being specific enough on the first run.

Comment: I would investigate angularjs and the ngTable plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataTables does not create new data for you.  Your best option is to create the new data server side and refresh the data (using [ajax.reload()](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)).  You can add rows to a DataTable with [.row.add()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add%28%29), but that won't save the data to the server.